# Java: Asynchronous I/O channel for reading and writing lines

Tags: java, asynchronous, text, io

I have an application that synchronously reads and writes lines of text using a `BufferedReader` and a `PrintStream` wrapping the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` of a `java.net.Socket` object. So, I can just use the methods `BufferedReader.readLine()` and `PrintStream.println()` and let the Java library split the input into lines and format the output for me.

Now I want to replace this synchronous IO with asynchronous IO. So I have been looking into `AsynchronousSocketChannel` which allows to read and write bytes asynchronously. Now, I would like to have wrapper classes so that I can asynchronously read / write lines using strings.

I cannot find such wrapper classes in the Java library. Before I write my own implementation, I wanted to ask if there are any other libraries that allow to wrap `AsynchronousSocketChannel` and provide asynchronous text IO.

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve? You can read millions of lines a second with `BufferedReader`. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @EJP: I want to read asynchronously. I do not want to block waiting for a line of text to be received over a socket. I want my code to be called when a complete line of text has been received.

Comment: @giorgio-b If you're not reading from the socket, what's going to receive that complete line?

Comment: And how does your application read something ... when nothing is there yet?

Comment: @giorgio-b I ask again. Why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: What do you mean? `AsynchronousSocketChannel` will call a callback method that I have to implement each time some bytes have been received. So I have to convert the bytes to String and keep reading until a complete line has been received. So, I am reading from the socket.

Comment: @Jägermeister: It reads something when some data is there. As long as no data is sent from the other end of the connection, no data will be read.

Comment: @EJP: My question is a general one. If I have synchronous byte IO and various wrappers for synchronous text IO on top of it, I expect to have the same for asynchronous IO.

Comment: It's all very well to expect it, but you don't have it. There is no line-oriented I/O in either NIO or asynchronous I/O.

Comment: @EJP: In fact I have not found anything like that in the documentation. That's why I am asking if any other Java library provides something similar.

Comment: That's what I said. It isn't there. Off-site resource questions are off topic here.

Comment: Have you found something? Or did you write your implementation? Did you shared it via Github?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: I have kept the synchronous implementation by now because I did not have time to work on it. The code is pretty awkward though.

Comment: `io.netty.handler.codec.LineBasedFrameDecoder` does the job

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
public void nioAsyncParse(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel, final int bufferSize) throws IOException, ParseException, InterruptedException {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
    BufferConsumer consumer = new BufferConsumer(byteBuffer, bufferSize);
    channel.read(consumer.buffer(), 0l, channel, consumer);
}


class BufferConsumer implements CompletionHandler<Integer, AsynchronousSocketChannel> {

        private ByteBuffer bytes;
        private StringBuffer chars;
        private int limit;
        private long position;
        private DateFormat frmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        public BufferConsumer(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, int bufferSize) {
            bytes = byteBuffer;
            chars = new StringBuffer(bufferSize);
            frmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            limit = bufferSize;
            position = 0l;
        }

        public ByteBuffer buffer() {
            return bytes;
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void completed(Integer result, AsynchronousSocketChannel channel) {

            if (result!=-1) {
                bytes.flip();
                final int len = bytes.limit();
                int i = 0;
                try {
                    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        byte by = bytes.get();
                        if (by=='\n') {
                            // ***
                            // The code used to process the line goes here
                            // ***
                            chars.setLength(0);
                        }
                        else {
                            chars.append((char) by);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception x) {
                    System.out.println("Caught exception " + x.getClass().getName() + " " + x.getMessage() + " i=" + String.valueOf(i) + ", limit=" + String.valueOf(len) + ", position="+String.valueOf(position));
                }

                if (len==limit) {
                    bytes.clear();
                    position += len;
                    channel.read(bytes, position, channel, this);
                }
                else {
                    try {
                        channel.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) { }
                    bytes.clear();
                    buffers.add(bytes);
                }
            }
            else {
                try {
                    channel.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) { }
                bytes.clear();
                buffers.add(bytes);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable e, AsynchronousSocketChannel channel) {
        }
};
```